# Using sscanf for the dynamic delimiters (inputted by users) in parsing an input string in C?

Tags: c++, c

I'm encountering a problem in parsing a string using sscanf() function.

My function gets 2 string parameters. One for input string and another one for a dynamic list of delimiters. How can I use `sscanf` to parse the input string with the defined delimiters inputted by users.

For example:

```
Myfunction(char * input_string, char * delimiter_list){
    scanf("%s", input_string);
    scanf("%s", delimiter_list);
    sscanf(input_string, ???...);
    ................
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use sprintf to create a scanf format string dynamically:

```
char fmt[256];

sprintf(fmt, "%%[^%250s]", delimiter_list);
sscanf(input_string, fmt, result);
```

Alternatively, consider using something like `strpbrk` instead:

```
const char *end;
size_t len;

end = strpbrk(input_string, delimiter_list);
if (end != NULL)
    len = end - input_string;
else
    len = strlen(input_string);

memcpy(result, input_string, len);
result[len] = 0;
```

Comment: @caf: yup -- part of why I suggested `strpbrk` instead.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `strtok`:

```
//makes the assumption that tokens has enought storage to hold all the substrings.
void Myfunction(char * input, char * delimiters, char **tokens){
    char *str = strdup(input); //not necessicary if you can modify input_string.
    char **tp = tokens;
    for(str=strtok(str, delemeters)); str; str=strtok(NULL, delimeters)){
        *(tp++) = str;
    }
    *tp = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will want to refrain from using strtok for several reasons. With the most important reason being that it alters the source string.

It's also not thread-safe, because it allows you to do this:

```
char source[] = "Testing, 1 2 3";
char *occurrence= strtok(source, ",");

while (occurrence!= NULL) {
    occurrence = strok(NULL, ",");
}
```

A good alternative would be to use strpbrk, as demonstrated in one of the earlier answers.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want something like strtok. look at this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/

```
int main ()
{
  char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";
  char * pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str," ,.-");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Still, it is not clear if what you want is this.